Knowing which Google Calendar API scopes to use and how to use them
I am trying to get my use of the Google Calendar API verified by Google but I don't understand what they are looking for.
When I added the api in the Google Cloud Console, I got some scopes by default. I don't know if I need them all.
My app will allow the user to enter in a date and time and when they click "save" the date and time will be saved to a Firestore db and then it will be added to their Google Calendar. That is all it will do.
I don't save any personal information in the process.
Here are the scopes they gave me:
Your non-sensitive scopes
Google Calendar API .../auth/calendar.calendarlist.readonly See the list of Google calendars you’re subscribed to
Google Calendar API .../auth/calendar.events.public.readonly    See the events on public calendars
Google Calendar API .../auth/calendar.settings.readonly View your Calendar settings
Google Calendar API .../auth/calendar.freebusy  View your availability in your calendars
Google Play Android Developer API   .../auth/androidpublisher   View and manage your Google Play Developer account
People API  .../auth/userinfo.email See your primary Google Account email address
Your sensitive scopes
Google Calendar API .../auth/calendar.acls  See and change the sharing permissions of Google calendars you own
Google Calendar API .../auth/calendar.acls.readonly See the sharing permissions of Google calendars you own
Google Calendar API .../auth/calendar.events    View and edit events on all your calendars
Google Calendar API .../auth/calendar.events.owned  See, create, change, and delete events on Google calendars you own
Google Calendar API .../auth/calendar.events.owned.readonly See the events on Google calendars you own
Google Calendar API .../auth/calendar.events.readonly   View events on all your calendars
The sensitive scopes need approval. Do I need the sensitive scopes since I am only adding an event to the calendar?
Thanks

Does this answer your question? What's the difference between the Google Calendar API scopes - calendar.readonly and calendar.events.readonly?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
